# How to replace certain values by NA in several rasters before computations?

Tags: r, raster

I am making some calculations with raster files.I am particularly calculating the moving average.
I would like to know hot to assign values to NA before any calculations.

```
Here is the code :
 files   <- list.files("C:final-2010", "*.envi", full.names = TRUE)
 files[round(files,3) ==  -339999995214436420000000000000000000000.000 ] <- NA
d1 <-  overlay(stack(files ),fun=function(x) movingFun(x, fun=mean, n=3, na.rm=TRUE))
```

But I got an error:

```
          Error in round(files, 3) : Non-numeric argument to mathematical function
```

I tried this  also:

```
  f=stack(files)
  f[round(f,3) ==  -339999995214436420000000000000000000000.000 ] <- NA
   movi <-  overlay(stack(f),fun=function(x) movingFun(x, fun=mean, n=3, na.rm=TRUE))
```

there was no error,but when i looked at the results I found that nothing has been changed.

Comment: `files` just contains a character vector of file names, not the data in the files. You have to read the data first.

Answer (score 4):

This is how you set NA to values in a single raster layer. Once you do that, you can stack ad libidum.

```
library(raster)
r1 <- raster(nrows=108, ncols=21, xmn=0, xmx=10)
r1[] <- runif(ncell(r1))
par(mfrow = c(1, 2))
plot(r1)
r1[500:1000] <- NA
plot(r1)
```

[image]

```
r <- stack(r1, r1, r1)
x <- list(c(100, 300), c(400, 600), c(800, 1000))
s <- mapply(FUN = function(x, y) {
  y[x[1]:x[2]] <- NA
  y
}, x = x, y = r)

plot(stack(s)) # not shown here
```

Comment: `RasterStack` can be thought of as a list. I've added an example.

Comment: This is an anonymous function. `x` and `y` could as well be `arg1` and `arg2`.